# After updating to iOS 9 my device is not supported by Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, device, xcode6.4

The iOS 9 (my device iOS) update is not supported by Xcode 6.4 for testing purposes. Is there a way to connect my device to Xcode for testing?

It is showing me these messages:

> iPhone may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xcode 6.4 doesn't contain iOS 9 SDK, that's why it isn't working. You need to update your Xcode to 7.0 (available on the AppStore)

Comment: love it  @Vive .your answer correctly work for me .. you save my time . Thanks

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.4 doesn't support iOS 9, If you want to debug your device then you have to update Xcode. And if you just want to check app in device then create a [diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) link and install in phone(which is tedious process).